# Get Video Url From Object Tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to get the video URL from the object tag using JavaScript. So how can I do it. For [example](http://www.ndtv.com/video/player/news/since-you-enjoy-holidaying-sushma-swaraj-s-jibe-at-rahul-gandhi/378677?vod-mostpopular), there is a news video played on the site. I check the code by using inspect element the video is embed in object tag.So if I want to fetch the video URL from that object how can I do it?

I want to video URL so I can watch that video later.

Comment: Try this $("embed").attr("src")

Comment: that's flash, I'm afraid you can't directly find the source url.

Comment: Yaa i know not directly.But there must be a way to do it indirectly.i Know it not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you object tag with some id property,

```
<object id="objSrc" data="audi.jpeg"></object>
```

The data of same can be retrieved using,

```
document.getElementById("objSrc").data
```

If you are using jquery,

```
$("#objSrc").attr('data')
```

Here data can be any URL you have.

Comment: Thx Umesh.yes i got the way u said.i treid it before .but in all the object tag they dont mention the video url in data attribute. for eg    you can check this site  http://www.ndtv.com/video/player/news/since-you-enjoy-holidaying-sushma-swaraj-s-jibe-at-rahul-gandhi/378677?vod-mostpopular       where they have object tag but no data attribute